# css instaframe effect on html page

Tags: html, css, image

[image]

I need to align images like this photo. My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.main
{
    width: 634px;
    height: 634px;
}
.img1
{
    width: 315px;
    height: 315px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="photo/01.jpg" class="main"><br>
<img src="photo/05.jpg" class="img1">
<img src="photo/01.jpg" class="img1">
<img src="photo/01.jpg" class="img1">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to create instaframe effect on html page. But I cant add images to the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floating to achieve your desired effect:

```css
.main {
  width:80%; /* width can be anything */
  overflow:auto; /* clears floating */
}

.main img {
  width:33.33%; /* images are responsive, usually 3 images per row (33.33) */
  height: auto; /* resize height based on width to keep image proportion */
  float:left; /* float images to the left */
  border:2px solid white; /* optional border */
  box-sizing:border-box; /* makes sure border does not break total width */
}

.main img.big {
  width:66.66%; /* big image takes 2/3 of grid size, so 66.66 of 100 */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="big">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

It is best to wrap the floated elements inside a common parent so that they do not affect the rest of page elements. In this case, the parent is `<div class="main">`.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/84j26vwp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 flexbox to achieve this;
See code below; you probably also want to use % or ems instead of fixed height/width;

using float as per answer above is more beautiful of course, flexbox is just one more way to achieve same results

**Demo:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xpmopts/1/)

```css
.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.rowContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.columnContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mainContainer {
  width: 450px
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="columnContainer">

      <div class="rowContainer">
        <img class="main">
        <div class="columnContainer">
          <img class="img">
          <img class="img">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rowContainer">
        <img class="img">
        <img class="img">
        <img class="img">
        <img class="img">
        <img class="img">
        <img class="img">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```